# Second Window is blank after a button was clicked in Main Window

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, window, toplevel

I have two python file, the first one is contain the mainWindow, second python file contains another Window. I manage to make the second window appear but the window is blank after it appear. Here is the screen shot of the error.
[image]

and here is what should show after the "Configuration" button clicks.
[image]

In main window file, I define the code like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import configureUAHChange as cA

class TracingInterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        root.minsize(width=700, height=520)
        root.maxsize(width=700, height=520)
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Grid.config(self)
        self.TracingMethod()
        self.logDetails()
        self.otherFunctionInterface()
        # Default window state
        self._configureUA_window = None

    def UAconfig_window(self):
        if self._configureUA_window is not None:
            return
        self._configureUA_window =cA.ConfigureUAinterface(self)

    def closeUA(self):
        # Destroy the 2nd and reset the value to None
        if self._configureUA_window is not None:
            self._configureUA_window.destroy()
            self._configureUA_window = None
```

This line is for the button click command:

```
self.configUAButton = Button(self.radioframe, text="Configuration",command=self.UAconfig_window)
```

Next, this is how I define the function in second python file

```
class ConfigureUAinterface(Toplevel):
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    master.minsize(width=700, height=520)
    master.maxsize(width=700, height=520)

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    Grid.config(self)

    master.title("UA Configuration")

    #Pre define combobox value in case suggestion
    self.value_of_combo='Identity Theft'

    #Run the all Function
    self.DateSelection()
    self.finish()
    self.UASuggestion()
    self.ConfigurationUA()
    self.suggestionCombo()
```

Please tell me how can modified my code to solve above error.

This is complete coding for main window :https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KKgYPbGMNNWBfPVazHfcM_NSFlv5eEpKg3_uXsvQsNE

This is complete coding for second window:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LuqJXIUrDMLfuz8gnZynZXUN6-SvFAyw9c-puJ3REPQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think there are some `root` that should be `master` in the `__init__` function of `TracingInterface`.

2) The master you pass to `ConfigureUAinterface` is not a window but a `TracingInterface` which is a frame and doesn't have `minsize`, `maxsize` and `title` methods.

3) I don't know why you use `Frame.__init__(self, master)` while `ConfigureUAinterface` inherit from a `Toplevel`.

Edit: 
Changes for the main window:

```
class TracingInterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        # 1) master instead of root (it was just a typo I think)
        master.minsize(width=700, height=520)
        master.maxsize(width=700, height=520)
        # Frame.__init__(self, master): redundant with super().__init__()
        Grid.config(self)
        self.TracingMethod()
        self.logDetails()
        self.otherFunctionInterface()
        # Default window state
        self._configureUA_window = None

    def UAconfig_window(self):
        if self._configureUA_window is not None:
            return None
        # 2) changed self which is a frame to the actual window self.master
        self._configureUA_window = cA.ConfigureUAinterface(self.master)
```

Changes for the second window:

```
class ConfigureUAinterface(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # replaced master by self since it's the Toplevel size we want to limit
        self.minsize(width=700, height=520)
        self.maxsize(width=700, height=520)

        # 3) The following is inapropriate since the widget 
        #    inherit from Toplevel, not Frame:
        #  Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #  Grid.config(self)

        # replaced master by self since it's the Toplevel title
        self.title("UA Configuration")

        #Pre define combobox value in case suggestion
        self.value_of_combo='Identity Theft'

        #Run the all Function
        self.DateSelection()
        self.finish()
        self.UASuggestion()
        self.ConfigurationUA()
        self.suggestionCombo()
```

I didn't modify anything else in the code and when I tried, it worked.

Comment: If i want to change the coding, how can i modified it with your suggestion, Regards